# Speakers not recognized when microphone is plugged in

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

Having a bit of a strange issue on 16.04.  I just got some new speakers for the office (3.5mm jack), but unfortunately they don't seem to be recognized by my computer.  I also have a Yeti microphone that's plugged in via USB.

When the microphone is plugged in, Sound settings shows only the microphone as a valid output device. I can select it and play sound through headphones connected to it, but can't make sound come through the speakers no matter what I try. This screenshot shows my sound settings when the mic is plugged in:

[image]

When the microphone is unplugged, no devices are listed under Sound settings for Output, but the sound *will* play through the speakers just fine.

The issue is that I would like to use the microphone as a microphone, and run my audio output through the speakers now.  How do I get my computer to recognize the speakers as a valid device with the microphone plugged in?

Comment: have you tried using pavucontrol ? it has a lot more options for configuring pulseaudio devices

Comment: @Amias Well, with pavucontrol I can get sound to play through the speakers, but I still don't see the speaker in the volume control settings. Will I always have to use pavucontrol to change audio output devices, then?

Comment: it sounds like a regression , i would raise it as a bug

Comment: @Amias well, if you'd like to post a short answer with how to do it with `pavucontrol`, that looks like the best answer I'm going to get.

Comment: Do you have a 3.5mm port that only accepts microphone? I feel the problem here is that the speaker priority for your microphone is higher than that for your speakers, and, while I don't have the knowhow to fix that issue, just moving the pin to a port that cant send audio should 'fix' it, at least as far as functionality goes.

Comment: The Yeti microphone is USB, so unfortunately I can't move it to a microphone-only port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing and opening `pavucontrol`, I was able to configure the computer to use the speakers as an audio device. They still don't show up as a device in the normal sound settings, but Ubuntu is successfully using them to play music, and that has stayed the default over a few reboots. I think as long as I don't touch anything, it should work.

Still don't know why it's not showing up under Sound Settings, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using pavucontrol ? it has a lot more options for configuring pulseaudio devices.

something looks odd with your microphone presenting an spdif output,
have your verified it works ok with other devices ?

Comment: The microphone has an output. I can plug headphones into it and hear just fine, but I'd rather plug things into my speakers.